# Sum 2 arrays based on indices defined in separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using Numpy and Pandas to generate a series of prices in .25 increments before creating another array of associated values from a dataframe.

I end up with an array of keys, and an array of values.

What is the best way to sum two sets of these key/value array pairs on their respective prices?

```
keys1 = np.array([1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75])
vals1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])

keys2 = np.array([1.25, 1.5])
vals2 = np.array([1, 1])
```

Desired result:

```
(1, 2, 2, 1)
```

Note: I'm not concerned with cases where the 2nd set has values that do not exist in the first set. Just looking for a clean way to add the 2nd set of values to the 1st set of values.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you worked with dataframes where these are actual keys and values? Then you can add the corresponding rows of the two df's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's [searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for this. This works just fine in your case as searchsorted returns the

> indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order

which are exactly the indices in `vals1` where the values of `vals2` should be added to.

So basically:

```
vals1[np.searchsorted(keys1, keys2)] += vals2
```

But keep in mind that this only works if both, `keys1` and `keys2`, are sorted **and** if `keys2` only holds elements that are also present in `keys1`.